# Adjusting column width based on treeview size no longer works when compiled

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

All is in the title ;)

column adjustment works when I run the script directly but not when I compile it to .exe.I have already checked all the dependencies or error messages in the console but everything is ok.

I use pyinstaller to compile my code.

In fact, I've a main window who call the right frame when i clic on a button.

Here is the main window code :

```
import customtkinter as ctkimport jsonimport pyautogui
```

```
from view.customer import CustomerViewfrom view.product import ProductViewfrom view.check_admin import CheckAdminViewfrom view.user import UserViewfrom view.cart import CartViewfrom view.check_bill import CheckBillView
```

```
from model.db_connect import db_connfrom model.config import *
```

```
def maximize_window():# Simuler un appui sur le bouton "Agrandir" de la fenêtrepyautogui.hotkey("winleft", "up")
```

```
class HomeView:def init(self, pseudo):self.width = Noneself.height = Noneself.is_window_maximized = Falseself.home_children = []self.current_frame = Noneself.pseudo = pseudoself.role = []
```

```
    self.get_role()

    self.width_config, self.height_config, self.maximized_config, self.error = read_config_window()

    if self.error == "Success":
        window_width = int(self.width_config)
        window_height = int(self.height_config)
        self.is_window_maximized = json.loads(self.maximized_config.lower())
    else:
        window_width = 1190
        window_height = 750
        self.is_window_maximized = False

    ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
    ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

    self.home = ctk.CTk()

    if self.is_window_maximized:
        self.home.after(50, maximize_window)

    screen_width = self.home.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.home.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
    y = (screen_height - window_height) // 2

    self.home.winfo_toplevel().minsize(1190, 750)

    self.home.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")
    self.home.title("Synergior")

    ##############################################################################################################
    # menu_frame
    self.menu_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.home)
    self.menu_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y", pady=15, padx=10)
    self.titre = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.menu_frame, text="Bonjour " + self.pseudo,
                              font=("Georgia", 25, "bold"))
    self.titre.pack(pady=30, padx=20)

    self.gestion_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.menu_frame, text="Gestion", font=("Georgia", 18, "bold"))
    self.gestion_label.pack(anchor="w", padx=20)

    self.gestion_canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(master=self.menu_frame, height=2, highlightthickness=0)
    self.line_id_gestion = self.gestion_canvas.create_line(0, 1, 1, 1, width=2)
    self.menu_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.update_canvas_width)
    self.gestion_canvas.pack(pady=5)

    self.products = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.menu_frame, text="Produits", font=("Georgia", 15, "bold"),
                                  command=self.open_product_frame)
    self.products.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    self.customers = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.menu_frame, text="Clients", font=("Georgia", 15, "bold"),
                                   command=self.open_customer_frame)
    self.customers.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    if self.role[0][0] == 1:
        self.user = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.menu_frame, text="Utilisateurs", font=("Georgia", 15, "bold"),
                                  command=self.open_users_frame)
        self.user.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    self.cart = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.menu_frame, text="Panier clients", font=("Georgia", 15, "bold"),
                              command=self.open_cart_frame)
    self.cart.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    self.consultation_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.menu_frame, text="Vérification",
                                           font=("Georgia", 18, "bold"))
    self.consultation_label.pack(anchor="w", padx=20, pady=(20, 0))

    self.consultation_canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(master=self.menu_frame, height=2, highlightthickness=0)
    self.line_id_consultation = self.consultation_canvas.create_line(0, 1, 1, 1, width=2)
    self.menu_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.update_canvas_width)
    self.consultation_canvas.pack(pady=5)

    self.customer_details = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.menu_frame, text="Administratif",
                                          font=("Georgia", 15, "bold"),
                                          command=self.open_details_frame)
    self.customer_details.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    self.bill_details = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.menu_frame, text="Facturation",
                                          font=("Georgia", 15, "bold"),
                                          command=self.open_bill_frame)
    self.bill_details.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    self.disconnection = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.menu_frame, text='Se déconnecter', font=("Georgia", 15, "bold"),
                                       command=self.disconnect)
    self.disconnection.pack(side="bottom", pady=30, padx=10)

    self.home.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

def get_role(self):
    conn = db_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT Role FROM Users WHERE Pseudo=?", self.pseudo)
    self.role = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

def save_window(self):
    self.width = self.home.winfo_width()
    self.height = self.home.winfo_height()

    self.is_window_maximized = self.home.wm_state() == 'zoomed'

    save_config_window(self.width, self.height, self.is_window_maximized)

def on_close(self):
    self.save_window()
    self.home.destroy()

def update_canvas_width(self, event):
    self.gestion_canvas.delete(self.line_id_gestion)
    self.line_id_gestion = self.gestion_canvas.create_line(0, 1, event.width, 1, fill="grey", width=2)

    self.consultation_canvas.delete(self.line_id_consultation)
    self.line_id_consultation = self.consultation_canvas.create_line(0, 1, event.width, 1, fill="grey", width=2)

def disconnect(self):
    self.save_window()

    self.home.destroy()

    from view.login import LoginView
    LoginView().run()

def run(self):
    self.home.mainloop()

#################################################################################################################
# Customer Frame
def open_customer_frame(self):
    if self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, ProductView):
        self.close_product_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckAdminView):
        self.close_details_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, UserView):
        self.close_user_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CartView):
        self.close_cart_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckBillView):
        self.close_bill_frame()

    for child in self.home_children:
        # Vérifiez si la frame CustomerView est déjà un enfant de la fenêtre principale
        if isinstance(child, CustomerView):
            # Si c'est le cas, rendez-la simplement visible et quittez la fonction
            child.pack()
            return

    customer_frame = CustomerView(master=self.home)
    customer_frame.pack(side="top", pady=15, padx=10, fill='both', expand=True)
    self.current_frame = customer_frame
    self.home_children.append(customer_frame)

def close_customer_frame(self):
    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, CustomerView):
            child.destroy()
            self.home_children.remove(child)

#################################################################################################################
# Product Frame
def open_product_frame(self):
    if self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CustomerView):
        self.close_customer_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckAdminView):
        self.close_details_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, UserView):
        self.close_user_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CartView):
        self.close_cart_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckBillView):
        self.close_bill_frame()

    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, ProductView):
            child.pack()
            return

    product_frame = ProductView(master=self.home)
    product_frame.pack(side="top", pady=15, padx=10, fill='both', expand=True)
    self.current_frame = product_frame
    self.home_children.append(product_frame)

def close_product_frame(self):
    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, ProductView):
            child.destroy()
            self.home_children.remove(child)

#################################################################################################################
# Administration Frame
def open_details_frame(self):
    if self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CustomerView):
        self.close_customer_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, ProductView):
        self.close_product_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, UserView):
        self.close_user_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CartView):
        self.close_cart_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckBillView):
        self.close_bill_frame()

    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, CheckAdminView):
            child.pack()
            return

    detail_frame = CheckAdminView(master=self.home)
    detail_frame.pack(side="top", pady=15, padx=10, fill='both', expand=True)
    self.current_frame = detail_frame
    self.home_children.append(detail_frame)

def close_details_frame(self):
    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, CheckAdminView):
            child.destroy()
            self.home_children.remove(child)

#################################################################################################################
# User Frame
def open_users_frame(self):
    if self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CustomerView):
        self.close_customer_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, ProductView):
        self.close_product_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckAdminView):
        self.close_details_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CartView):
        self.close_cart_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckBillView):
        self.close_bill_frame()

    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, UserView):
            child.pack()
            return

    user_frame = UserView(master=self.home)
    user_frame.pack(side="top", pady=15, padx=10, fill='both', expand=True)
    self.current_frame = user_frame
    self.home_children.append(user_frame)

def close_user_frame(self):
    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, UserView):
            child.destroy()
            self.home_children.remove(child)

#################################################################################################################
# Cart Frame
def open_cart_frame(self):
    if self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CustomerView):
        self.close_customer_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, ProductView):
        self.close_product_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckAdminView):
        self.close_details_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, UserView):
        self.close_user_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckBillView):
        self.close_bill_frame()

    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, CartView):
            child.pack()
            return

    cart_frame = CartView(master=self.home)
    cart_frame.pack(side="top", pady=15, padx=10, fill='both', expand=True)
    self.current_frame = cart_frame
    self.home_children.append(cart_frame)

def close_cart_frame(self):
    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, CartView):
            child.destroy()
            self.home_children.remove(child)

#################################################################################################################
# Facturation Frame
def open_bill_frame(self):
    if self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CustomerView):
        self.close_customer_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, ProductView):
        self.close_product_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CheckAdminView):
        self.close_details_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, UserView):
        self.close_user_frame()
    elif self.current_frame and isinstance(self.current_frame, CartView):
        self.close_cart_frame()

    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, CheckBillView):
            child.pack()
            return

    bill_frame = CheckBillView(master=self.home)
    bill_frame.pack(side="top", pady=15, padx=10, fill='both', expand=True)
    self.current_frame = bill_frame
    self.home_children.append(bill_frame)

def close_bill_frame(self):
    for child in self.home_children:
        if isinstance(child, CheckBillView):
            child.destroy()
            self.home_children.remove(child)
```

Here is the code who don't work for column when it's compiled :

```
from tkinter import ttkfrom tkinter.font import Font
```

```
import customtkinter as ctkfrom tkcalendar import DateEntry
```

```
from model.db_connect import db_conn
```

```
class CheckBillView(ctk.CTkFrame):def init(self, master):super().init(master)
```

```
    self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self, text="Vérification Facturation", font=("Georgia", 30, "bold"))
    self.label.pack(pady=20)

    self.main_filter_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
    self.main_filter_frame.pack(pady=5, padx=5)

    ###########################################################################################################
    # Filter Frame

    self.filter_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.main_filter_frame)
    self.filter_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    self.bill_date_var = ctk.StringVar()

    self.bill_date_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.filter_frame, text="mois à facturer")
    self.bill_date_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=5)
    self.bill_date_entry = DateEntry(master=self.filter_frame, textvariable=self.bill_date_var,
                                     date_pattern="dd/mm/yyyy")
    self.bill_date_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2, padx=5)

    self.search_button = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.filter_frame, text="Rechercher", command=self.create_list_frame)
    self.search_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    ###########################################################################################################
    # Validation Frame

    self.validation_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.main_filter_frame)
    self.validation_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    self.bill_send = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.validation_frame, text="Facture envoyée", command=self.send_bills)
    self.bill_send.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    ###########################################################################################################
    # Panel Frame

    self.panel_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
    self.panel_frame.pack(side="bottom", padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("Treeview", rowheight=25, font=('Georgia', 8), background='#1e1e1e')
    style.map("Treeview", background=[('selected', '#0078d7')])

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.panel_frame, columns=(
        'Nom client', 'Nom produit', 'Version', 'Unité', 'Commentaire', 'Prix unité', 'TVA', 'Date facture'),
                             show='headings')
    self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.panel_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.panel_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Add a vertical scrollbar
    scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self.panel_frame, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set)
    scrollbar_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nse")

    # Add a horizontal scrollbar
    scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self.panel_frame, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
    self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set)
    scrollbar_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="swe")

def create_list_frame(self):
    self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

    # Récupérer la date sélectionnée dans le widget
    selected_date = self.bill_date_entry.get_date()
    selected_month = selected_date.month
    selected_year = selected_date.year

    # Utiliser le mois et l'année pour filtrer la base de données
    query = f"SELECT * FROM Have WHERE End_Date IS NULL AND MONTH(Bill_date) = {selected_month} AND YEAR(Bill_date) = {selected_year}"

    conn = db_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute("SELECT ID_customer, Name FROM Customer")
    row_customer = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute("SELECT ID_products, Name FROM Products")
    row_product = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    # Créer un dictionnaire pour stocker la correspondance entre l'ID du client et son nom
    id_to_name_dict = {id_: name for id_, name in row_customer}
    id_to_product_name_dict = {id_: name for id_, name in row_product}

    self.tree.heading('Nom client', text='Nom client', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Nom produit', text='Nom produit', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Version', text='Version', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Unité', text='Unité', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Commentaire', text='Commentaire', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Prix unité', text='Prix unité', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('TVA', text='TVA', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Date facture', text='Date facture', anchor='center')

    self.tree.tag_configure('oddrow', background='#e8e8e8')
    self.tree.tag_configure('evenrow', background='#c4c4c4')

    for i, row in enumerate(result):
        for j, item in enumerate(row):
            if item is None:
                row[j] = ""

        # Convertir l'ID du client en nom à partir du dictionnaire id_to_name_dict
        client_name = id_to_name_dict.get(row[1], "")
        product_name = id_to_product_name_dict.get(row[2], "")

        row_data = [client_name, product_name, row[5], row[6], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[14]]

        # Déterminer si la ligne est paire ou impaire
        if i % 2 == 0:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row_data, tags=('evenrow',))
        else:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row_data, tags=('oddrow',))

    self.adjust_column_widths()

    self.tree.update()

def adjust_column_widths(self):
    # Permet au widget de se mettre à jour
    self.tree.update_idletasks()

    # Largeur maximale de toutes les colonnes
    col_width = max(
        Font().measure(col) for col in self.tree["columns"]) + 10

    for col in self.tree["columns"]:
        # Ajuste la largeur de toutes les colonnes pour qu'elles aient la même largeur
        self.tree.column(col, width=col_width, anchor='center')

def send_bills(self):
    pass
```

Any idea?

how to solve this problem (between only script and compiled code)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).